# Flurl Extension for multi-part Put

Tags: flurl

I have a Flurl implementation already working for multi-part Posts (json plus file attachment).  I need to add an extension for Put that works the same way. 
 So far I've failed to replicate one.

My Post code...

```
resp = await url
.PostMultipartAsync(mp => mp
    .AddString("manifest", ManifestJSON)
    .AddFile("attachment", new MemoryStream(sendFile.ToArray()), sendFilename));
```

How would I build a comparable ".PutMultipartAsync" method to take its place?

Answer (score 3):

Got it.

```
var content = new Flurl.Http.Content.CapturedMultipartContent();
content.AddString("manifest", ManifestJSON);
content.AddFile("attachment", new MemoryStream(sendFile.ToArray()), sendFilename, "application/zip");

resp = await url
.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Put, content);
```

Easy.

Answer (score 2):

What you did should work great for a one-off. If you wanted to be really robust about it so it feels like first-class Flurl functionality, you could follow the [Flurl.Http extensibility pattern](https://flurl.dev/docs/extensibility/#extending-flurlhttp) and add these extension methods:

```
public static class MultipartPutExtensions
{
    public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PutMultipartAsync(this IFlurlRequest request, Action<CapturedMultipartContent> buildContent, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var cmc = new CapturedMultipartContent(request.Settings);
        buildContent(cmc);
        return request.SendAsync(HttpMethod.Put, cmc, cancellationToken);
    }

    public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PutMultipartAsync(this Url url, Action<CapturedMultipartContent> buildContent, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        return new FlurlRequest(url).PutMultipartAsync(buildContent, cancellationToken);
    }

    public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PutMultipartAsync(this string url, Action<CapturedMultipartContent> buildContent, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        return new FlurlRequest(url).PutMultipartAsync(buildContent, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

These are modeled directly after the `PostMultipartAsync` [implementations](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/blob/dev/src/Flurl.Http/MultipartExtensions.cs).